# Apache http server reply 418 ("I'm a teapot") - json argument, TCP request using PUT from arduino

Tags: php, json, apache, http, arduino

I am trying to send data (json formatted string) as argument to Apache HTTP server with PUT method from arduino. The reply from server is 418 teapot reply.
This is my first project using TCP request, http, php - so I do not have a solid background in this direction.

The string :

```
{%221%22:%22FE005F719444%22,%222%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22,%223%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22}
```

TCP request:

```
PUT /proxyJson/index.php/?YOUR_data={%221%22:%22FE005F719444%22,%222%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22,%223%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22} HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 192.168.xx.xxx
User-Agent: 192.168.xx.xxy
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Apache access log:

```
192.168.xx.xxy - - [27/Dec/2016:19:50:22 +0200] "GET /proxyJson/index.php/?YOUR_data=    {%221%22:%22FE005F719444%22,%222%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22,%223%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22} HTTP/1.1" 400 226
```

The script works just fine if enter data directly in browser.

[image: php script result]

What am I missing ?
Thanks for reply and support.

George

Comment: You should consider editing your post so as to make it more readable.

Comment: What's up with the superfluous spaces?

Comment: I removed the spaces. In short the server does not like the request and I don't know why. The same code worked fine on http://www.firebasedemo.hol.es/index.php/?YOUR_data={"0":"tag1","1":"tag2"}

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your request.
The first line should be:

```
PUT /proxyJson/index.php/?YOUR_data={%221%22:%22FE005F719444%22,%222%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22,%223%22:%22ooooooooooxo%22} HTTP/1.1
```

Without the:

```
200 OK
```

Also, I recommend sending your data in the body of the request.
So your request would be:

```
PUT /proxyJson/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.xx.xxx
User-Agent: 192.168.xx.xxy
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 58
Connection: close

{"1":"FE005F719444","2":"ooooooooooxo","3":"ooooooooooxo"}
```

That is the purpose of the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers.